# Threads and Fork

Tags: c, multithreading, process, fork

Let's say we have this code:

```
main    

some code...
fork()
fork()
some code
```

The question is:
How many threads are running?

Thank you !

Comment: What's your best guess? Bear in mind, each time you `fork()` you get one extra new process and each process has one thread.

Comment: @JeremyP I say there are three threads: one for the parent one for the fork1 and another for fork2. Is that true?

Comment: The first fork creates an extra process, so there are now two processes. So how many times does the second `fork()` get executed?

Comment: @JeremyP Oh you mean that there is a thread from the parent a thread from the child1 an extra thread from the child1 due to the second fork, and finally a thread due to the child2. So in the end there are 4 threads. Right?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: @JeremyP Nooo that means I answered wrong. Anyway, thank you very much for the help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I'm not going to write a full answer to the question, but there's nothing to stop you from doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Jeremy I figured out the answer and want to share it with you.

In general if we have a fork() a child is created. Unless we have a different code for the child the child runs the code of the parent (aka the code under fork() ).
So in this example the 1st fork will create a new process as it will run the second fork.

So we have 1 thread for the parent. 1 second thread for the child1 from fork1. 1 third thread from the child1 due to fork2. And finally a thread from the child2.
So in total there are 4 threads.